# Unable to locate a search suggestion element Selenium C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

[image]

Hi,
I am trying to locate and click on the element that comes up in the search box when I type some name. 
Can someone please help me out to find & click on the name?
I've use searching by XPath - contains(@class, '...'); contains(text()) etc,  but everytime it fails.

When I inspect the element, I see this HTML:
[image]

Comment: Never mind! Got my own solution.
Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 1):

Use Action class and move to the search suggestions element first then perform your action.

```
Actions action = new Action(driver);
action.MoveToElement("Locator of the element").Perform();
```

Use the above method to try accessing the search suggestion element.

Comment: I tried it but the focus is shifted to the 'Overview' section - top left.
I did this: OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions actions = new OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions(driver);
                actions.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(),'Acura West')]"))).Perform();

Can you please help. I'm kinda stuck

Comment: Verify if there are multiple matches occurs in finding the element or verify the element is present inside the frame

Comment: I'm trying this: 

**PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
String advName = rowValue[0];
IWebElement adv =  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@placeholder, 'Add filter')]"));
string popupWindowHandle = finder.Click(adv.SendKeys(advName));**

So, the popup only triggers when I type in some text in the 'Add filter' (search box basically)
I don't know how to do that using: string popupWindowHandle = finder.Click(adv.SendKeys(advName));  I get an error here 'cannot convert from 'void' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement'